# Adding FirstOrDefault to my query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

How do i add first or default to my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    var customers = from s in db.TicketDetails
                    select s;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        //search criteria
        customers = customers.Where(s => s.SupportRef.Contains(searchString));
    }
    return View(db.TicketDetails.ToList());
}
```

I need to make sure my results only return 1 record. If they return `null` then I need to pass in dummy values.

Comment: Clarify what you want return. Customers or the first entry of the collection?

Comment: I want the user to search the form for an ID and then my query is supposed to find the record. Once its found the record i want to display that 1 row value in a text box.

Comment: what will happen if the `searchString` is null? what do you want then?

Comment: I think i have 2 problems here. I cant get my value to show in the text box because MORE than 1 record are being returned by the query and if its NULL then my page will just crash.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure how many items you have returning from the query.

- If more than 2 return your default value.
- If nun return your default value.
- If the item returned is null return your default value.
- Otherwise you have one valid item in your collection and you return it:

All together you can write it this way:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    var defaultReturnValue = //you default dummy object

    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        return View(defaultReturnValue);

    var customers = (from s in db.TicketDetails
                     where s.SupportRef.Contains(searchingString)
                     select s).Take(2).ToList(); // execute query here so not to execute it twice

    return View(customers.Count > 1 ? defaultReturnValue :
                                      customers.FirstOrDefault() ?? defaultReturnValue);
}
```

*I've added the `Take(2)` so the generated query will take up to 2 records and so, in a case that there is more than a single record it will still not bring all of them*

Comment: Thanks for the info! I get the following error because i am not displaying the value correctly:
`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'SignalRChat.Models.TicketDetail', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SignalRChat.Models.TicketDetail]'.`

Comment: yes because your model is still a `IEnumerable<T>` instead of a single `T`. If you know you want one item only, like you said above, then change it from a collection to a single `T`

Comment: I fixed it using this: `@model SignalRChat.Models.TicketDetail`

Comment: I believe SingleOrDefault throws an `InvalidOperationException` exception if two records are found (not returns null) see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - I was wrong about it. Thanks for showing me. much appreciated. Corrected answer

Comment: This code will execute two queries, one to get the count and one to get the first item, it is better to use `FirstOrDefault()`, and if the result is `null` then return a default dummy object

Comment: @Haitham Saddad - it won't. I've added ToList above and even commented on it to explain that it is there so it won't execute twice

Comment: This is even worse, as it will fetch all the data from the database while he only needs one record, the call for .`ToList()` should be omitted and use only `FirstOrDefault` as this will generate a `select top 1` query which will get one record only from the DB

Comment: @Haitham Saddad - as his data in any case should not contain more than 1 record with that predicate (though the parameter name is searchString in a comment it is specified that it is an ID) the it is not a problem. Further more I've added Take(2) to be sure